# facebook api retrieving friends pictures who posted on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous

I am trying to create a Facebook wall using the objects from the users feed. However, what I cannot seem to do is get the picture of the friends who have posted on my wall.

I am currently using an if statement to check the feed object for the from property below. I can get the id from the from property, but that only allows me to get it if I do another api call within the loop to construct the wall. However, since it is async i cannot return the values, and I also can't concatenate it with the src attribute. Any suggestions on how to get around this problem?

```
{
  "data": [
      {
      "id": "64582869534783990_343788612678878", 
      "from": {
        "id": "32458397413435340", 
        "name": "User Name"
      }, 
      "message": "this is my message", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/144375679690/posts/245786252634978"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/245786252634978/posts/245786252634978"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "description": "Your friends", 
        "value": "ALL_FRIENDS", 
        "friends": "", 
        "networks": "", 
        "allow": "", 
        "deny": ""
      }, 
      "type": "status", 
      "status_type": "mobile_status_update", 
      "application": {
        "name": "App Name", 
        "id": "245786252634978"
      }, 
      "created_time": "2014-11-08T22:26:06+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-11-08T22:26:06+0000"
    }
    ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use field expansion

`me/feed?fields=from{id,name,picture}`